# pyramid of stars in Java

Tags: java, string-formatting

How can I do this in java?:

```
    *  *  *  *  *  *  *
       *  *  *  *  *
          *  *  * 
             *
          *  *  *
       *  *  *  *  *
    *  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

This is my answer ^_^

```
for (int i=7;i>=1;i-=2 ) {
for (int j=i;j<7;j++ ) {
System.out.print(" " );
}for (int k=1;k<i+1;k++) {
System.out.print(" *" );
}System.out.println( );
 }   
for (int i=3;i<=7;i+=2 ) {
for (int j=7;j>i;j--) {
System.out.print(" " );
}for (int k=1;k<=i;k++ ) {
System.out.print(" *" );
}System.out.println( );

}
```

I would also like to know how to do this:

```
    *                 *
    *  *           *  *
    *  *  *     *  *  *
    *  *  *  *  *  *  *
    *  *  *     *  *  *
    *  *           *  *
    *                 *
```

I'm trying now

Comment: I remember doing this assignment in school, sadly I don't have it lying around anymore. But it's fair practice for using loops

Comment: very basic question, i would suggest you to read school books. All these patterns are there only.

Comment: lol I'm graduated from university and I'm studied Graphic Design and i don't know anything in java

Comment: its not about java. it about logic, and how you implement nested loop, space counting. star counting, that it :)

Comment: I was senior school teacher for 5 yrs, so i said this. I can solve this and earn 25 point, but what will you earn and learn??   I can give you hint... break this pattern in two parts horizontally from mid till u have * * * * * * *. for upper part one set of nested loop and then for below another set of nested loop is required.

Comment: but I'm learning now 3d design in maya and cinmea 4d, i can't understand anything in programming language, and i want to use this code one time. thank you Anoop Vaidya :(

Comment: how i can learning "pyramid of stars in Java" ? step by step

Answer (score 1):

Think of a Square of 7 rows full if `*`.

Then, what you have done is:

[image]

And What You need to do is:

[image]

Convert red lined area that you have done previously into spaces and Add * to the blank area

**Write Your own code yourself, It will help You in future  :)**

**Edit** : Okay fine, For Your reference Only:

```
       for (int i=0;i<4;i+=1 ) {
            for (int j=0;j<7;j++ ) {
                if(j>i&&j<(7-(i+1))){
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print(" *" );
            }
            System.out.println( );
        }  
        for (int i=4;i<7;i+=1 ) {
            for (int j=7;j>0;j-- ) {
                if(j<(i+1)&&j>(7-(i))){
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print(" *" );
            }
            System.out.println( );
        }
```

Comment: codeMaker, okay I'm trying O.o

Comment: how i can do this please

http://i.stack.imgur.com/FYNPC.png

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use 2 loops, one for the top half and one for the bottom. Nest a for loop in both which handles the stars and/or another to handle spaces.

Anything more, and i will have to write the code :)

Once you get this, you will be able to do the second one.

This question is more of a test of logic than language skill. If you are having problems *because* its java, then i would suggest concentrating more on the language basics and then trying to code.

Comment: for (int i=7;i>=1;i-=2 ) {
    for (int j=i;j<7;j++ ) {
    System.out.print(" " );
    }for (int k=1;k<i+1;k++) {
    System.out.print(" *" );
    }System.out.println( );
     }   
    for (int i=1;i<=7;i+=2 ) {
    for (int j=7;j>i;j--) {
    System.out.print(" " );
    }for (int k=1;k<=i;k++ ) {
    System.out.print(" *" );
    }System.out.println( );
    
    }

Comment: @BakirOdeh Whatever you try add it to the question, below the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1, j = 7; i <= 7 && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < i - 1; i2++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int m = i - 1; m < j; m++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    for (int j2 = j; j2 > 0; j2--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

just for upper half to give you some direction, it may not be efficient solution it's just for working purpose

Comment: how i can do this please http://i.stack.imgur.com/FYNPC.png